# Ordenar dados por data no Firebase

Tags: firebase, typescript, angular, order

Gostaria de ordenar os dados retornado do Firebase pela Data de vencimento, no momento estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
this.Collection = document.collection('values', ref => ref.orderBy('data_vencimento'));
```

Mas como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo, não está ordenando corretamente, existe outras formas de ordenar pela data? Posso fazer um sort() no Observable retornado do Firebase?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na verdade está ordenando corretamente, porém não vai ter o resultado desejado porque está ordenando como numa string qualquer não como uma data no formato pt-BR, se tu mudar para o formato para `yyyy-mm-dd`, terá o resultado desejado

Comment: Ok, irei verificar isso...

Comment: No banco precisa ser salvo no formato YYY-MM-DD para o orderby funcionar corretamente, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Cara o ideial seria guardar, a data em [timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) em uma nova propriedade por exemplo:

```
const data = new Date();

const meuObjeto = {
    data: data.toLocaleDateString(),
    timestamp: data.getTime()
};
```

Assim você podera compara tanto diferenças de tempo quanto ordenar etc...

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade está ordenando corretamente, porém não vai ter o resultado desejado porque está ordenando como numa string qualquer não como uma data no formato pt-BR, se tu mudar o formato para `yyyy-mm-dd`, terá o resultado desejado.

Sugiro que uso o padrão americano no banco e faça uma máscara das datas no front-end, por exemplo:

```
var data = new Data //Retorna no formato Tue Mar 13 2018 15:23:51 GMT-0300 (-03)
data.toLocaleDateString() //Retorna no formato 13/03/2018
```